# Given a key, how do I read the value from a table via the API?

Tags: move, move-lang, aptos

Imagine I have a move module that looks like this.

`Move.toml`

```
[package]
name = 'friends'
version = '1.0.0'

[dependencies.AptosFramework]
git = 'https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core.git'
rev = 'testnet'
subdir = 'aptos-move/framework/aptos-framework'

[addresses]
friends = "81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e"
```

`sources/nicknames.move`

```
module friends::nicknames {
    use std::error;
    use std::signer;
    use std::string::String;
    use aptos_std::table::{Self, Table};

    const ENOT_INITIALIZED: u64 = 0;

    struct Nicknames has key {
        // A map of friends' nicknames to wallet addresses.
        nickname_to_addr: Table<String, address>
    }

    /// Initialize Inner to the caller's account.
    public entry fun initialize(account: &signer) {
        let nicknames = Nicknames {
            nickname_to_addr: table::new(),
        };
        move_to(account, nicknames);
    }

    /// Initialize Inner to the caller's account.
    public entry fun add(account: &signer, nickname: String, friend_addr: address) acquires Nicknames {
        let signer_addr = signer::address_of(account);
        assert!(exists<Nicknames>(signer_addr), error::not_found(ENOT_INITIALIZED));
        let nickname_to_addr = &mut borrow_global_mut<Nicknames>(signer_addr).nickname_to_addr;
        table::add(nickname_to_addr, nickname, friend_addr);
    }
}
```

I then published the module (to testnet), initialized `Nicknames` to my account, and then added an entry:

```
aptos move publish
```

```
aptos move run --function-id 81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e::nicknames::initialize
```

```
aptos move run --function-id 81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e::nicknames::add --args string:dport address:81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e
```

Now that my table is on-chain with some data, how would I go about reading the value of the `dport` key. I think I can use the API for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you can use the API for this! First let's get some information about your table.

Let's look at the resource you've deployed to your account from the above Move module. First let's construct the struct tag (aka resource ID / handle), it looks like this:

```
<account_address>::<module>::<struct_name>
```

In your case:

```
0x81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e::nicknames::Nicknames
```

Because there can only be one of each resource in an account in the Aptos blockchain, we can use this to uniquely identify the resource in your account. Using this we can then get the table handle. A table handle is a globally unique ID (so, not just within the bounds of your account) that points to that specific table. We need that to make any further queries, so let's get that first:

```
$ curl https://fullnode.testnet.aptoslabs.com/v1/accounts/0x81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e/resource/0x81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e::nicknames::Nicknames | jq .
{
  "type": "0x81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e::nicknames::Nicknames",
  "data": {
    "nickname_to_addr": {
      "handle": "0x64fa842ed2c9da130f0419875e6c101aeea263882fadee3257b13f1bb4d7d41d"
    }
  }
}
```

Explaining the above:

- Hitting `https://fullnode.testnet.aptoslabs.com/v1/accounts/0x81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e/resource/<name>` lets us get a specific resource on an account.
- We then request specifically `0x81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e::nicknames::Nicknames`. The two addresses happen to be the same here, but that's just because we're using the same account, another example could be `0x1::aptos_coin::AptosCoin`.
- We can see the handle there, `0x64fa842ed2c9da130f0419875e6c101aeea263882fadee3257b13f1bb4d7d41d`.

Using this handle, we can now query the API:

```
$ cat query.json
{
  "key_type": "0x1::string::String",
  "value_type": "address",
  "key": "dport"
}

$ curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary "@query.json" https://fullnode.testnet.aptoslabs.com/v1/tables/0x64fa842ed2c9da130f0419875e6c101aeea263882fadee3257b13f1bb4d7d41d/item
"0x81e2e2499407693c81fe65c86405ca70df529438339d9da7a6fc2520142b591e"
```

Explaining the above:

- The request to get an item from a table via the API is a POST request. The data comes from this `query.json` file.
- `key_type` is the type of the key in the table. You can see from the original declaration of `nickname_to_addr` that this was `0x1::string::String`.
- `value_type` is the type of the value. Its type was `address`, a special type that isn't deployed at any particular module (hence the lack of `<addr>::<module>::`.
- `key` is the key that we're querying in the table.

If hypothetically the key used in the table was more complex, like a struct instead of a single value like a string, you could represent that struct as JSON in the request, e.g.

```
{
  "key_type": "0x1::string::String",
  "value_type": "address",
  "key": {
    "first_name": "Ash",
    "last_name": "Ketchum",
  }
}
```

This is the extent of what you can do with the API right now. Namely, reading values given you know the key ahead of time. If you want to do the below things, you need to query an indexer:

- Iterate through all the keys in a table.
- Get the entire table, both keys and values.

I'll write an answer on how to do this later.