# How do I get all the keys in a table?

Tags: move-lang, aptos

Assume I have a table deployed on chain. I know if I have a key, I can lookup the value like this:

[Given a key, how do I read the value from a table via the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74296605/given-a-key-how-do-i-read-the-value-from-a-table-via-the-api)

But what if I don't know the key? How do I lookup all the keys in a table via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Indexer API

You can make a query to the `table_items` table. You will need to paginate to get all the items:

```
query MyQuery {
  table_items(
    where: {table_handle: {_eq: "0xd71c4400706e2addf04f8728fbc4f0a87d0612456cdcec95ae8fea0a4bd31b67"}}
    limit: 100
    offset: 0
  ) {
    key
  }
}
```

Each request increase `offset` by `limit` (e.g. in this case, by 100 each time). Continue until the response has fewer than 100 items.

Learn about the indexer API here: https://aptos.dev/indexer/api/.

### Node API

Unfortunately with regular tables there is no way to do this via the node API right now.

### Alternatives

- If you know you'll only ever have a small number of items (like < 100), you could use [SimpleMap](https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/blob/main/aptos-move/framework/aptos-stdlib/sources/simple_map.move). This can be queried directly with the node API.

Comment: About SimpleMap, how many items are allowed? Please let me know about how "small" number of items.

Comment: Generally nothing more than 10-100, just as a rough answer.