# Given a key, how do I read the value from a iterable table via the API?

Tags: move, aptos, move-lang

I have a struct like this:

```
struct MarketData {
markets: IterableTable\<u64, Data\>

,
whitelist: IterableTable\<address, address\>,
isOpenForAll: u64
}
```

Given a key, how do I read the value from an iterable table via the API?

I tried but got this error:
[image]

Comment: Hey, this has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74296605/given-a-key-how-do-i-read-the-value-from-a-table-via-the-api. For this request (lookup a value), there is no difference between Table and IterableTable. Voting to close this one :)

Comment: yeah, i'm seen that post and already read your answer... i'm tried but got this error. i don't know why because in this case my whitelist: IterableTable<address, address>,
This is my link api: https://fullnode.testnet.aptoslabs.com/v1/accounts/0x2314c0306981255544e50a155130428225438dfe65cf774db57d7bc8e58234a8/resource/0x3d896ece493e911ad60043fef383aa6aeb899e9d384da9afa7f6aec022dfdd83::testPredictionMarket::MarketData
i'm so glad if you help me

Comment: anyone...???????

Comment: I don't think this question provides enough information for us to answer it. Please reach out in the Aptos discord and we'll help you out.